# Child doesn't update after state change in parent

Tags: reactjs, components

After the first render of PlayerContainer another change of movieId in my Parent component doesn't cause a rerender of PlayerContainer and I don't understand why.

Parent component:

```
export default class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      renderPlayer: false,
      movieId: ''
    }
  }

  handleCallback = (num) => {
    this.setState({ movieId: num, renderPlayer: true }, () => {
      console.log('MovieID ' + this.state.movieId)
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { movieId } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.state.renderPlayer
          ? <PlayerContainer movieId={movieId} />
          : null}
        <Selection handleClick={this.handleCallback} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The Selection component receives a click and causes the state change in the parent, which then is passed on to PlayerContainer:

```
export default class PlayerContainer extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            movies: [],
            DataisLoaded: false
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("https://a.url.com/movies/" + this.props.movieId + "/1/")
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((json) => {
                this.setState({
                    movies: json,
                    DataisLoaded: true
                });
            })
    }

render() {
        const { DataisLoaded, movies } = this.state;
        return (
            <div className='wum__playercontainer section__padding' id='player'>
                {!DataisLoaded
                    ? <h1>Please wait a second...</h1>
                    : <ReactPlayer
                        url={movies.link}
                        ...
                        ...
                    />}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you only use this.props.movieId in the componentDidMount. If you want to render again your component like this you have to implement the componentDidUpdate function so it will render each time a props will change :

```
componentDidUpdate() {
// fetching again with new props
}
```

You could even specify the DidUpdate function using the prevProps param :

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
   if(prevProps.movieId !== this.props.movieId) {
      //fetch again your data
   }
}
```